# Dealing with Two Elements with same ID in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I know that IDs should be unique, however I have to deal with a page that has two elements with the exact same ID, when I try to get the element by ID it only selects the first one. How can I access the second element with the exact same ID as the first in JavaScript?

First element

```
<INPUT id=Edit class=Design_01 style="IME-MODE: active" type=submit value=　Edit>
```

Second element

```
<INPUT id=Edit class=Design_01 style="IME-MODE: active" type=submit value=　Edit>
```

Comment: Could you try this one? `document.querySelectorAll("#Edit")`

Comment: You CANNOT have two elements with the same ID

Comment: It would save you a lot of time to use a class. Convention suggests that you place quotes around every value for each key inside an html tag, and in this way you can give your div two classes: in quotes, multiple classes can be specified by adding a space between: `<input id="Edit" class="Design_01 editClass">` now that element belongs to two classes, and you can use `document.getElementsByClassName("editClass")` (returns an array)

Comment: @HenryDev You can have two elements with the same ID, it's not correct but you can have it. And if you aren't the one responsible for creating the page sometimes you have to deal with that fact. Gintoki If you ARE the one that created this page and are responsible for those duplicate IDs, fix that.

Comment: @RickCalder you are correct mate

Comment: @RickCalder unfortunately I am not the one who created this page so I can't fix it, I will try the solutions proposed here though and check if they work or not.

Comment: @HenryDev  Are you sure about that? When I open Youtube and I inspect the thumbnails, they are all having the same exact ID (id="thumbnail"). The titles for the videos are also all using the same ID. (id="video-title"). Not to mention there's also a ton of other elements like this that are sharing the same ID... How do you explain this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I know that IDs should be unique, however, I have to deal with a page
>   that has two elements with the exact same ID

As you've stated it should be unique hence if you have more than one `id` attribute with the same name then that's not valid HTML.

> How can I access the second element with the exact same ID as the
>   first in JavaScript?

wouldn't it be easier to use `getElementsByClassName` since having two `id` attributes with the same name is invalid HTML?.

with that in mind, you can use `getElementsByClassName`.That may be more suited to your requirements.

**Example:**

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("Design_01"); // x is an array
var firstElement = x[0]; // get first element
var secondElement = x[1]; // get second element
```

**Relevant Readings:**

- [**HTML DOM getElementsByClassName() Method**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp)
- [**JavaScript Arrays**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)

Comment: Actually you can, you can't in jQuery by ID but you can in vanilla js

Comment: *"since you cannot have more than one id attribute with the same name?"* - Yes you can. It's invalid HTML, sure, but the browser still accepts it, and you can still select by ID using methods other than `.getElementById()`. But yes, using a class is better, assuming those are the only elements with the class in question.

Comment: @nnnnnn that's exactly what i stated "then that's not valid HTML" but thanks anyway i'' update my answer.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't objecting to the whole answer, just that phrase.

Comment: @nnnnnn good to get feedback anyway. main reason I joined StackOverflow. Still studying :). Thanks once again.

Answer (score 12):

```
var bothElements = document.querySelectorAll("[id='Edit']");
```

you can then access the second one with:

```
bothElements[1].
```

Comment: for the record ("#Edit") works too and is a little less verbose.

Comment: Thank you for actually answering the question.

Comment: You answered the question, thank you!

Comment: You did it. Thanks Mike.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the class selector to select all of them and then nominate the one you want.

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('Design_01');
var requiredInput = inputs[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

While these techniques may very well *work*, I'd advise caution if you are building a solution that might have two or more of the same ids on a page, as these techniques may be unreliable. In my experience, invalid HTML will almost certainly cause problems elsewhere.

See the spec:
https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute

> The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID).

While you may get this to work in your environment, different browsers, implementations and frameworks can handle it differently. Browser updates might break your solution without warning.

I strongly recommend you use a class or resolve the issue with the HTML.

Comment: It seems pretty clear from the wording of the question that the OP doesn't control the HTML on this particular page. The question itself already acknowledges that ID should be unique.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm sure we've all dealt with issues where we can't change markup. But I thought it was worth pointing out some of the consequences of building atop quirks. OP presumably can't control the user's environment either.

Comment: He didn't create the page and has no control over the HTML. So this isn't really a solution to the problem at hand, and as such should have been a comment.

Comment: Sorry guys, I didn't gather from "I know IDs should be unique, however…" that he didn't write the HTML he posted. Back in the day people used to do "but it works anyway" stuff all the time and often caused weird issues down the line.

Comment: I get your point, if the question is just supposed to be for academic interest, then there are several ways to get the ids, and the literal answer is what OP wants. But if he and future searchers are looking for help to build something reliable I think it's reasonable to have the official doc should be among the answers.